# Django ModelAdmin get_urls not registering correctly

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a custom url and page to use to display certain data on the admin side of Django for a model of mine.

Here is my code in admin.py

```
class AdminUserEventHistory(admin.ModelAdmin):

def get_urls(self):
    # get the default urls
    urls = super().get_urls()
    
    # define urls
    my_urls = [
        path('userhistory/<int:pk>/>/', 
 self.admin_site.admin_view(self.admin_user_event_view))
    ]
    
    # make sure here you place the new url first then default urls
    return my_urls + urls

def admin_user_event_view(self, request):
    context = {}
    
    context['history'] = None
    return HttpResponse('Success!')
```

Then towards the bottom I register it with

```
admin.site.register(EventAttendee, AdminUserEventHistory)
```

The url should be /admin/events/eventattendee/userhistory/1/ if i'm not mistaken as I want it to take in the primary key of the user so I can pull info based on the user id. Sadly I am getting the following error.

> Event Attendee with ID “userhistory/1” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?

I do have two test records in that table and able to display them with the /admin/events/eventattendee/2/change. Did I miss something? This is all based on the Django documentation for 3.2 found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls)

Comment: Should `'userhistory/<int:pk>/>/'` be `'userhistory/<int:pk>/'` instead?

Comment: I beleive that was or issue. Some more reading and I found how to override the AdminSite to django with a sub class. I am using that now. As in the future I will be replacing the entire django admin area to my own templates. Similiar to like a phpbb admin area but for my specific project. Thanks for help